# Version control system with incremental updates

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial

I want to build an automatic update system for a game that I am working on and I thought I could just use an existing version control system for this purpose.

My game consists of many small files and at the moment I am just using git with a git pull. So every time the client starts it does a `git pull` to always get to the newest version.

But the small problem that I have is that as far as I know git doesn't allow incremental updates. This means that if I do a `git pull` and it gets interrupted the whole update is lost because otherwise the local git repo would be in an inconsistent state.

I already knew that I might have abused git a bit but I am wondering if there are other version control system that allow an incremental git pull.

Does something similar exist?

Answer (score 1):

I think git pull already does what you want.

A pull is a fetch followed by a merge. So, if fetch gets interrupted, nothing has been changed in your working dir (that would only be done by the final merge, once all objects have been transferred).

What I'm not sure about now, is whether after an interrupted fetch, a subsequent fetch would resume or if it would start anew. I would bet it's the first option (resume), but I'm not sure just now. Try it (turn off network in the middle of a fetch, for example).

Comment: I think he wants whatever was was downloaded before the interruption to not have to be re-downloaded, so not just the consistent state, but also the download-time savings.  Or maybe I'm misreading it.  Either way it's a terrible idea. :)  just use one of the many, fine, free auto-update libraries for whatever platform you're on.